# Failed to start kernel - Jupyter in VsCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[image: Error]
I've been trying to use Jupyter for my basic python code and it doesn't work. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Python and Jupyter in VsCode but seemed like it's still the same.

Comment: What if you run the command in `.ipynb` file?

Comment: @Shayan still showing the red text on the right like the picture above

Comment: Maybe it would be better to open an issue or search for similar issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter).

Comment: @Shayan I just find out that it must be given the same name for it to run (both .py and .ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jupyter file is `*.ipynb`

A python file is `*.py`

In `vscode` just make a blank `*.ipynb` file and it will be automatically recognised.